# Approach to check a PHP class integrity

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a script to check my PHP class file matches the MySQL database table schema or not.

Database Table "brands"

```
Column       Type          Null    Extra             Key
==============================================================
id           INT(11)       NO      AUTO_INCREMENT    Primary
brand_name   VARCHAR(50)   NO
founded      INT(11)       NO
status       INT(11)       NO      Default: 1
created_on   DATETIME      NO
updated_on   DATETIME      NO
```

And my PHP class file "Brand.php" is as follow:

```
<?php
class Brand {
  public $id;
  public $brand_name;
  public $founded;
  public $status;
  public $created_on;
  public $updated_on;

  public function __construct() {
     // constructor here
  }
}
?>
```

what is the best approach to check the corresponding properties exist or not?

One approach I think of is to use a PHP script to examine the above PHP class:

one downside of using [get_object_vars($obj)](http://www.php.net/get_object_vars) is that this function can only get **public** properties as it is called outside the class. Any better alternatives?

Since I'm using Unix-based system, using shell script is also feasible.

Comment: [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) allows you to look at properties of a class, whether public/protected/private

Comment: `ReflectionClass` seems promising, thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaker please add your suggestion as answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What about [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)?

```
$brand = new Brand();
if(!property_exists($brand, 'brand_name'))
{
    throw new Exception("Brand doesn't match table's schema.");
}
```

Comment: `property_exists()` is useful as well, only if PHP 5.3+ is installed (luckily I'm using PHP 5.4). With PHP >= 5.1 & < 5.3, the result is inaccurate on `private` and `static` cases.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is described in the manual. I saw that RefectionClass was suggested. It is a good option, because of its compatibility! Though if you  execute `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` and then loop through the columns with `property_exists` it would be easier (less typing ^^).  ReflectionClass is powerful if you want to do more complex things with `Brand()` (for example). If I wanted to check whether the class matches the table schema, I'd prefer `property_exists` (if I have the PHP version it requires, ofc) :)